# Updating frames in pixi.js on interaction only

Tags: pixi.js

I'm creating a pixi.js 6.0.4 app and seeing performance issues on slower computers.  CPU and/or GPU are high.

In Chrome dev tools if I profile miro.com which seems to use pixi I notice that the FPS only spikes if I actually interact with the application.  e.g.

[image]

If I profile my app the FPS is constantly high.  e.g.

[image]

I'm thinking this probably has a big impact on performance.

I am using angular and ngZone, creating the application as follows:

```html
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
this.app = new PIXI.Application({
    backgroundColor: 0xefefef,
    autoDensity: true
});
this.SetCanvasSize();
});
```

How would I set pixi.js up to only update frames on interaction please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `PIXI.Application` which is a wrapper around "Renderer", "Ticker" and "Stage" - see: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/blob/dev/packages/app/src/Application.ts#L35

This means it will create Ticker which will run `Renderer.render` method ~60 times per second (using `requestAnimationFrame`). This is probably what is causing CPU/GPU usage.

Maybe you should try creating custom game loop:

https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v5-Custom-Application-GameLoop#custom-gameloop

then try to reduce frequency of `renderer.render(stage);` - so dont call it 60 times per second but maybe 20?

And/or you can modify it to call `renderer.render(stage);` not on every frame , but only if certain condition is true - for example "on interaction" (as you described it).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will try these things.  Greatly appreciated.